# How to set PHPTools preferences in Eclipse 4.7.2?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt, phpcodesniffer

I recently reinstalled my system and Eclipse PDT, now I'm faced with the following problem.

I seem unable to open the workspace preferences for CodeSniffer. Via `Window` / `Preferences` / `PHP Tools` / `PHP CodeSniffer`, I get two error messages:
- "Could not accept changes", "The currently displayed page contains invalid values."
- "Problem occurred", "java.lang.NullPointerException"

CodeSniffer is actually working in the background; it's messages appear in the `Errors` view. But its preferences cannot be set.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Kind regards,

FWieP

Answer (score 0):

CodeSniffer (and PTI in general) is no longer maintained and as far as I know doesn't work well with PDT 5.0 and recent DLTK (probably even earlier).